# How to shuffle the rows in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array with x columns, each with a yx1 cell. I would like to randomize the "rows" within the columns. That is, for each yx1 cell with elements a_1, a_2, ... a_y, I would like to apply the same permutation to the indices of a_i.

I've got a function that does this,

```
function[Oarray] = shuffleCellArray(Iarray);

    len   = length(Iarray{1});
    width = length(Iarray);
    perm  = randperm(len);

    Oarray=cell(width, 0);

    for i=1:width;
        for j=1:len;
            Oarray{i}{j}=Iarray{i}{perm(j)};
        end;
    end;
```

but as you can see it's a bit ugly. Is there a more natural way to do this?

I realize that I'm probably using the wrong data type, but for legacy reasons I'd like to avoid switching. But, if the answer is "switch" then I guess that's the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a cell array of column vectors, such as

```
Iarray = {(1:5).' (10:10:50).' (100:100:500).'};
```

In that case, you could do it this way:

```
ind = randperm(numel(Iarray{1})); %// random permutation
Oarray = cellfun(@(x) x(ind), Iarray, 'UniformOutput', 0); %// apply that permutation
                                                           %//  to each "column"
```

Or converting to an intermediate matrix and then back to a cell array:

```
ind = randperm(numel(Iarray{1})); %// random permutation
x = cat(2,Iarray{:}); %// convert to matrix
Oarray = mat2cell(x(ind,:), size(x,1), ones(1,size(x,2))); %// apply permutation to rows
                                                           %// and convert back
```

Comment: Works great! I should really learn more about the higher-order programming that's available in matlab.

Comment: [This](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) could be a good start