# How to sort lines of a text file by first word?

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file in this format :

```
22 BLBL asas saaa212 x:12 y:123
66 BLadsBL asas saaa212 x:12 y:123
32 BLadsBL asas saaa212 x:13212 y:123
66 BLadsBL asas saaa212 x:1332 y:123
```

How to create a new .txt file with these lines sorted by the first value?

Comment: Ps i dont care about speeds, just the simpliest code

Comment: For the future, please avoid tagging something with an irrelevant language.

Comment: yes i did, i did it with keeping indexes of used lines and just running over the file again and again, (and doing intecept) but this is rly ugly code and i hope someone will gimme abatter idea, i dont want a code just a right way of thinking about it

Comment: How are you reading the file? Is each line a string, or are you breaking it into different fields? Are they in an array, a cell array, structure, table, or something else? Do you want to sort on the first *word* or the first *value*? e.g. would the first line be sorted on `22` or `BLBL`? Have you looked at `sort` and `sortrows`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inpfid = fopen('InputFile.txt'); %This .txt file contains the data you gave in the question
allData = textscan(inpfid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
% Read in the first word from each row of data
outcellarray = regexp(allData{:},'^([\w\-]+)','match');
% Store all the first numbers into a single cell array and sort them
[~, ind] = sort(str2double(vertcat(outcellarray{:})));
% Creating a cell with the required order
output = cellfun(@(x) x(ind), allData, 'UniformOutput', 0);
% Making it into a form useable for writing a text file
output= output{:}; 

outfid=fopen('OutputFile.txt','wt+'); %Creating an output file
for k = 1:length(output)-1
  %Writing the data
  fprintf(outfid,output{k});
  fprintf(outfid,'\n');
end
fprintf(outfid,output{end});
% You can loop from 1 to length(output) and skip the last line 
% but it'll append an extra line at the end of the output file
fclose(outfid); % Closing the output file
```

**Comparison of Input and Output Files:**

[image: comparision]

---

**P.S:**

✶ Make it sure that both input and output files are at your current path or provide full paths like: *'D:\Assignment\InputFile.txt'*

✶ I used/copied the code/ideas from:

**①** https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357800/5698672

**②** https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041474/3293881

**③**  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28348768/5698672

So give these answers a vote up too if it solves your problem.